# Unable to change default geodatabase with arcpy.env.workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, database

Even after I set the path for the default database with arcpy environment variable, ArcMap does not change the default database directory?

At first my arcpy.env.workspace looks like below:

```
>>> arcpy.env.workspace
u'C:\\Users\\g.bharani@cgiar.org\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default1.gdb'
```

[image]

The Default1.gdb is highlighted by bold font.

Now I will try to set Gurminder as default gdb through the arcpy.env.workspace variable.

```
>>> arcpy.env.workspace
u'C:\\Users\\g.bharani@cgiar.org\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default1.gdb'
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\g.bharani@cgiar.org\Documents\ArcGIS\Gurminder.gdb"
>>> arcpy.env.workspace
u'C:\\Users\\g.bharani@cgiar.org\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Gurminder.gdb'
```

Even after refreshing the Catalog the default gdb is still Default1.gdb, the Catalog looks like following:
[image]

Because of this I am not able to store data in my customized default directory.

The results of clip, resample and other tools are still getting stored in Default1.gdb although I have change the arcpy.env.workspace to Gurminder.gdb

Why is it happening so?

Comment: discussion on how to get at this from a script https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197926/setting-default-gdb-from-arcpy (no solution yet)

Answer (score 3):

The `arcpy.env.workspace` is used to set the current working directory or current workspace environment from which you can read and write your data. It will not change the default workspace.

If you need to change the default working space, check [Setting the default geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sn0000000t000000.htm).

Also, check if period "." and "@" in your path can cause a problem or not.